# Different results from Simplify and Reduce given inequality (x/y^2 != 0 && x != 0)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In:

```
Simplify[x/y^2 != 0 && x != 0]
```

Out:

```
x != 0 && y != 0
```

However, if we use `Reduce` instead:

```
Reduce[x/y^2 != 0 && x != 0]
```

the result is:

```
x y != 0
```

So does Mathematica consider `x != 0 && y != 0` and `x y != 0` to be equivalent?

If so, what command can I use to convert from one form to another?